# How to use multiple css toggle switches in one page with js or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/757vnetp/)

I'm trying to make a toggle switch that will drain the color from an image when toggled. I was directed to a tutorial that helped me make the switch but it is all css and therefore without making a new class name for every single switch used I can't re-use it(that I know of)
What is the best js or jquery to allow me to use this toggle multiple times.

The issue is that when I click on any of the switches it always animates the first one only.

```
<div class="switch">
        <input id="cmn-toggle-7" class="cmn-toggle cmn-toggle-yes-no" type="checkbox">
        <label for="cmn-toggle-7" data-on="Color" data-off="B&W"></label>
</div>
```

Comment: First of all you reuse same id in all boxes, so that could be a start

Comment: To clarify what @crollywood said:  it's invalid HTML to have more than one element with the same id.  That's what classes are for.  Id's must be unique.

Comment: I know that but I don't want to have to change the id and animation for each switch because I have 12 of them. I know there is an easier way with js but I can't find the exact code

Answer (score 2):

Because you have the same ID for each checkbox and the same `for` attribute for each label, the toggle switches are all pointing to the first checkbox.

You need to have a different `id` and corresponding `for` for each toggle switch.

Here is an Updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/757vnetp/1/

Comment: I just tried changing the ID's I thought I'd need to add css for each different ID but I don't so I guess I can just change the ID's. Sorry

Comment: @Shniper you should target a class instead of the ID to avoid that